# Regex for epi week date format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate epiweek date format

```
Ex format : ww YYYY (32 2014)
```

I have tried with below format but not working

```
^\d{1,2}d{4}$
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Try `^\d{1,2}\s\d{4}$`

Comment: you just skipped the space in between `\s`

Comment: Be "careful" this will also match `99 9999` [for example] And I dont think there is 99 weeks :D

Comment: Thanks it worked , can you make it as answer

Comment: But do you really want to match `99 9999`? :)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : Basically i need to restrict week up to 53 , more that than should not allow

Comment: @Prashobh why not use simple js logic here - `var items = str.split(/\s+/); var isValid = !isNaN(item[0]) && item[0] < 53 && !isNaN(item[1])`

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks, but I will go with regex approach as I need to apply this to handsontable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regexp that will limit from 0 to 53.

```
^([0-4]?[0-9]|5[0-3])\s\d{4}$
```

We are look for a string that `^` start with number from 0  `[0-9]` to 49 `[0-4]?[0-9]` 
or 5  `5` followed by 0, 1, 2 or 3 `[0-3]`; followed by a space [or tabulation] `\s`, and then 4 number `\d{4}`.

Test : https://regex101.com/r/9ekEzh/1

As commentary point out, you could have the week 00, 01 .. and so on
If you don't want them :

```
^([0-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-3])\s\d{4}$
```

Test : https://regex101.com/r/9ekEzh/3

Update again, if you don't want the week 0 to be part of the regexp :

```
^([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-3])\s\d{4}$
```

Test : https://regex101.com/r/9ekEzh/4

Comment: Is week `00` valid ??

Comment: Well I don't know, I will give the 2 solutions then ;)

Comment: `^([0-9]|[1-4]?[0-9]|5[0-3])\s\d{4}$` shouldn't it be `^([1-9]|[1-4]?[0-9]|5[0-3])\s\d{4}$` ?

Comment: I've correct it, but no since I think week 0 is valide, but I update the answer  in order to add that ;) Thanks